# pyQt4 drawing a rectangle when a button is clicked

Tags: python, button, focus, pyqt4, drawrect

**The Objective**

I am attempting to draw a rectangle in my window when a button is clicked.

**The Problem**

When I use the button to allow the rectangle to be drawn it draws the rectangle just behind the button:
[Rectangle behind button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqytx.png)

If I minimize and then reopen the window it draws the rectangle correctly so I assume it is a problem with focus but when I attempted to change the focus it didn't help.

*Edit: Doing something with the original window when the button is clicked draws the rectangle in the right place. For example:*

```
self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black; color: white")
```

*This is a really messy solution though.*

**The Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    draw = False

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()
        self.test = self

    def initUI(self):      

        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 400, 400)

        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Paint', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(self.buttn)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50, 50)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Paint')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):

        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
            self.drawRectangles(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):

        if self.draw:
            qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(000, 000, 255))
            qp.drawRect(0, 0, 90, 60)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def buttn(self):
        self.draw = True


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method appears to work and does not seem to be too messy:

```
self.update()
```